# Add the debug symboles by using maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm trying to add the debug symboles by using mave-compiler-plugin (so that I'll be able to access the method parameters names). 
Following the available configurations that can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/%E2%80%A6), 
Here is my maven-compiler-plugin configuration

```
                        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <debugLevel>lines,vars,source</debugLevel>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Untill now, I have no success.

Can someone please let me know how to add the debug symboles by using maven?

Comment: Legal values for `debugLevel` are `none`, `lines`, `vars` and **`source`** (i.e. *not* `sources`).

Comment: THX, I updated the question with source (and not sources...). Still, no progress.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `<fork>true</fork>` according to the [maven-compiler-plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) for `compilerArgument`.

> Sets the unformatted single argument string to be passed to the compiler if fork is set to true.

Not sure if it's required but you may want to add `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>` and `<version>#.#.#<\version>`.

Also, as @JonK mentioned in the comments, you need `source` instead of `sources` for `debugLevel`.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding <fork>true</fork> , didn't solve the problem.